# taskset core numbers question

Tags: linux, unix, central-processing-unit, multi-threading, hyperthreading

I have quad core CPU with hyper threading enabled. So I have 8 logical cores. I want to limit my application to use only 4 cores and I want this 4 cores to be different physical cores. Which taskset options (core numbers) should I use? :

- taskset -c 0,1,2,3 command
  or
- taskset -c 0,2,4,6 command

Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear on the Linux terminology, you have 8 logical "processors" distributed among 4 physical "cores". You want to pick 4 logical processors that correspond to 4 distinct cores.

Answer (score 6):

You can see which cores are on which processors by taking at look at `/proc/cpuinfo`. For example, you will see on a machine with a dual core cpu:

```
processor   : 0
(snip)
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
```

for the first core on the processor and:

```
processor   : 1
(snip)
core id : 1
cpu cores   : 2
```

on the second.

So, generally speaking, I think you would want:

```
taskset -c 0,1,2,3
```

or:

```
taskset -c 4,5,6,7
```

Comment: Um. just curious. If "processor 0" corresponds to [physical] core 0, and "processor 1" corresponds to [physical] core 1…then doesn't that mean that, to have all 4 cores selected, both 0 and 1 must necessarily be selected? (That is, 0/2/4/6 would only use physical cores 0 and 2?)

Comment: In your example, `processor:0` is on `core:0` and `process:1` is on `core:1`. Those two processors are on different cores, so assuming that the pattern continues, the argument to `taskset` should be `-c 0,1,2,3`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [CPU Set (cset)](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Cpuset_management_utility/tutorial) to create a CPU shield group for your application. This way you can ensure that real cores are being used for the important work. I typically disable hyperthreading (on Nehalem systems) for my realtime and low-latency applications.

Here's a tutorial for creating groups of CPUs for specific applications/processes using cset, which is a little more organized than taskset. https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Cpuset_management_utility/tutorial

As far as determining the core count and location assignments, take a look at: http://dag.wieers.com/blog/is-hyper-threading-enabled-on-a-linux-system

A quick run of the utility linked on a quad-core Nehalem with hyperthreading enabled shows:

```
[root@XXX ~/hwloc-1.0.3]# ./utils/lstopo 
Machine (7980MB) + Socket #0 + L3 #0 (8192KB)
  L2 #0 (256KB) + L1 #0 (32KB) + Core #0
    PU #0 (phys=0)
    PU #1 (phys=4)
  L2 #1 (256KB) + L1 #1 (32KB) + Core #1
    PU #2 (phys=1)
    PU #3 (phys=5)
  L2 #2 (256KB) + L1 #2 (32KB) + Core #2
    PU #4 (phys=2)
    PU #5 (phys=6)
  L2 #3 (256KB) + L1 #3 (32KB) + Core #3
    PU #6 (phys=3)
    PU #7 (phys=7)
```

Comment: This still does not explain if taskset uses physical or logical indexing. If I run `taskset -c 0,1,2,3` on the system above, will it bind to the first two physical cores (logical PUs 0-3) or to the first logical PU on each physical core?

Answer (score 1):

You can use like:

`taskset -c -p 0-3 pid`